# Как правильно делить приложение?

Tags: php, yii2, ооп, mvc

Хочу делать всё правильно, потому интересуюсь. 
Есть контроллер `SiteController` с `actionRegistration`, который отображает страницу регистрации. Страница - это множество форм, множество ajax (это всё в планах). Например, есть форма, которая отправляет на добавление данные в таблицу базы данных `people`. Для этой таблицы есть модель `People`. А дальше вопросы

- куда мне правильнее отправлять данные аяксом - нужно создать в контроллере новый action (`actionAddPeople`) или же все запросы должны быть к `actionRegistration`? Т.е. в этом экшены я буду все аяксы разделать и принимать решение, что делать и т.п.
- Куда выносить логику работы с полученными данными. Например, если я добавляю нового человека, то я принимаю данные, проверяю их через модель, сохраняю через модель. Если что-то не так, то выкидываю исключение. Это всё писать в `actionRegistration` или же вынести как отдельный метод класса `SiteController`. Или же вынести его как метод модели `People`?

Сейчас начал всё писать, учиться. И возникли такие вопросы. На данный момент у меня отдельно `actionRegistration` для вывода страницы регистрации. И отдельный 
 `actionAddPeople` для отправки на него ajax запросов. И в нём вся логика работы с запросом

```
/**
 * Записывает в БД данные нового человека, принимая их по ajax
 *
 * @return string
 * @throws HttpException
 */
public function actionAddNewPeople()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->request->isAjax) throw new HttpException('404', 'Ошибка. Недопустимый метод');

    try {
        $peopleModel=new People();
        $peopleModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
        $peopleModel->save();
    } catch (Exception $e){
        throw new HttpException('404', $e->getMessage());
    }

    return json_encode([
        'id_people' => $peopleModel->getPrimaryKey(),
        'message' => 'Данные нового человека успешно записаны',
    ]);
}
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: `if (!Yii::$app->request->isAjax)` должен кидать 400 по стандарту, а не 404

Comment: @user3127286 Спасибо. А второе исключение что должно бросать?

Comment: Второе исключение должно отдавать 500 или 503.

Comment: Так-же вам нужно проверять нет ли ошибок валидации. И Если они есть, то можно возвращать 200 (обычный ответ) и json со списком полей и ошибок. Тут лучше покопать, как это делается в Yii2. По идее есть стандартные методы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**
Одно действие - один метод.

`actionRegistration` отрисовывает форму регистрации
`actionAddNewPeople` принимает ajax конкретной формы, валидирует, сохраняет и отдает список ошибок (если нужно)

**2)**

Выносить в отдельный метод контроллера не нужно. Т.к. контроллер предназначен только для приема запроса, возможно, первичной обработки параметров и проверки доступа. Дальше он передает эти параметры в модели/менеджеры и пр. и возвращает результат.

Так же контроллер несет ответственность за возвращаемое значение.

Выносить в отдельный метод в модели не вижу смысла.
По сути, что вы делаете в данном методе:

1. Проверяете, корректный ли запрос. (Контроллер)
2. Загружаете элементы в модель. (Контроллер)
3. Обрабатываете ответ, и это тоже контроллер.

И этот контроллер прекрасно все делает **стандартными методами** модели, городить из них метод просто чтобы вызывать это одной строкой неправильно.

Отдельный метод в модели можно будет создать если появится какая-то дополнительная логика сохранения или валидации входных данных, которую не реализовать **стандартными возможностями модели**.

Например не делать в контроллере проверку входных данных, а отдать это модели.

P.S.: Если этой логики будет много, то можно и вынести, но при этом не забывать про слои приложения. Какой компонент за что отвечает.

**Почему так.**

Сайт/приложение со временем может масштабироваться. И, к примеру, сегодня у вас регистрация только здесь, а завтра через API в мобильных приложениях либо через соц. авторизацию. Правильно распределенная по слоям логика и [принцип единой ответственности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) поможет вам избежать багов.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развёрнутый и чётко сформулированный ответ!